# Doctrine ORM - Order by a relation field of a relation

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I've got a problem... I'm doing a loop on a collection, but I want it to be ordered by a target's field.

The collection I'm looping on :

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=CompoEtapeScenarioCahierCampagne::class, mappedBy="compoScenarioCahierCampagne", cascade={"remove"})
 */
private $compoEtapeScenarioCahierCampagnes;
```

"etape" is a CompoEtapeScenarioCahierCampagne field :

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Etape::class, inversedBy="compoEtapeScenarioCahierCampagnes")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
 */
private $etape;
```

"ordre" is a Etape field :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $ordre;
```

So when I'm looping on **$compoEtapeScenarioCahierCampagnes**, I want them to be ordered by **$etape.ordre**

Anyway I can do this ? The problem is that I can't do a query because my loop is already in another loop and so on.

**EDIT :**

The loop looks like this :

```
{% for etpScnCdrCmp in entity.compoEtapeScenarioCahierCampagnes %}
    {# etpScnCdrCmp is basically $compoEtapeScenarioCahierCampagne #}
    {# But I want those to be orderedBy etpScnCdrCmp.etape.ordre #}
{% endfor %}
```

**EDIT 2 for more explanation :**

I wanna loop on $compoEtapeScenarioCahierCampagnes as if this ORM annotation could work (where ordre is a Etape's  field) :

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=CompoEtapeScenarioCahierCampagne::class, mappedBy="compoScenarioCahierCampagne", cascade={"remove"})
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"etape.ordre" = "ASC"})
 */
private $compoEtapeScenarioCahierCampagnes;
```

Comment: Didn't you try this https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.9/tutorials/ordered-associations.html ?

Comment: Yes, I tried to add :

`@ORM\OrderBy({"etape.ordre" = "ASC"})`

But I can't access 'ordre' since it's not directly a field of **$compoEtapeScenarioCahierCampagnes**

Comment: What exactly do you mean saying "can't access"? Can you show an error returned? Also, I suppose that for this to work all relations should be eagerly loaded.

Comment: Yeah of course. The returned error is : `An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unrecognized field: etape.ordre").` Indeed, *etape* is a field, and *ordre* is a field of *etape*. I tested to add : `fetch="EAGER"`, the error doesn't show anymore, but the ordering doesn't work either.